# Tetrahedron incenter iteration tree

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

This is driven more by curiosity than by research,
but nevertheless may be of some interest.

Start with a regular tetrahedron $T$ with corners $(a,b,c,d)$,
and let $x$ be its incenter—the center of the largest inscribed sphere.
Partition $T$ into four tetrahedra, with corners at 
$$(a,b,c,x), \; (a,b,d,x), \; (a,c,d,x), \; (b,c,d,x) \;.$$
And now iterate the process: Find the incenters of those four tetrahedra,
partition each etc.
Connecting the incenters forms a tree, whose convex hull is a regular tetrahedron:

---

[image: TetraReg]

---

I was hoping that the same process for an irregular tetrahedron would
lead to a similar tetrahedral hull, but it seems more complicated:

---

[image: Tetrar16]

---

The question is:

> ***Q***. To what shape does the hull of the incenter tree approach
>   as the number of iterations goes to $\infty$?

Perhaps it still approaches a tetrahedron, but just much more slowly?
The above shows $8$ iterations.

(Incidentally, replacing "incenter" by "centroid" appears to lead to
polyhedra that approach filling out the entire interior of 
the original $T$—less interesting behavior.)